# I want to create Wordpress menu by these code.But how i create?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My HTML code is

```
<ul class="mainNavigation">
    <li>
        <a href="index02b3.html?page=features_single" title="features" data-hover="Features"><span>Features</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I convert it into WordPress menu?

Actually I want include in wordpress menu   `title="features" data-hover="Features"`

Comment: Please expound on this question.  I have no idea what you are asking.  A lot more information is needed for this to be a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

For setting a custom title you might want to open your Admin Panel and go to `Appearance -> Menus -> Your Menu -> Your Link -> Title`

For setting another custom attribute different than the title (here `data-hover`) I am redirecting you to this well detailed answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-wordpress-menu-item

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) article.

Firstly, you will need to **register** your menu.

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Secondly, you then have to make use of `wp_nav_menu()` in your theme templates. This will display the menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) );
```

**Refs:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu